# Transferring destructor calls to a dedicated thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, memory-management

I am optimizing C++-code and have a situation where the destructor-calls take a significant amount of time.

I then coded this little class for fun, just to see if I could simply transfer the destruction to another thread, and it actually seems to work.

So this is my question about the code:

Does the code do what I think it does (without any major pit-falls or side-effects)? I.e. transfer ownership of the data in the shared_ptr from the caller's thread to another thread, and thereby transferring the cost of freeing the memory to the other thread.

```
#pragma once

#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

namespace test {

  class Cleaner {
    struct State {
      std::queue<std::shared_ptr<void>> queue;
      std::mutex mtx;
      std::condition_variable condition;
      bool cancelled;
      bool done;
    };
  public:
    Cleaner()
      :
      _state(std::make_shared<State>()),
      _thread(&runCleanerloop, _state)
    {
    }

    ~Cleaner() {
      {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_state->mtx);
        _state->done = true;
      }
      _state->condition.notify_all();
      _thread.join();
    }

    template <typename T>
    void run(std::shared_ptr<T>& data) {
      {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_state->mtx);

        // Push a copy to the queue to be released by the thread.
        _state->queue.push(data);

        // Reset the input in the caller's thread.
        data.reset();
      }
      _state->condition.notify_all();
    }

    static void runCleanerloop(
      const std::shared_ptr<State>& state
    ) {
      std::shared_ptr<void> data;

      bool done = false;

      while (true) {
        // Wait for data to appear in queue.
        {
          std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(state->mtx);

          state->condition.wait(lock, [&state] {
            return state->cancelled || state->queue.size() || state->done;
          });

          if (state->cancelled || (!state->queue.size() && state->done)) {
            done = true;
          }
          else {
            data = state->queue.front();

            state->queue.pop();
          }
        }
        state->condition.notify_all();

        if (done) {
          return;
        }

        // Release the data inside this thread.
        data.reset();
      }
    }
  private:
    std::shared_ptr<State> _state;
    std::thread _thread;
  };
}
```

Intended usage:

```
#include "cleaner.h"

void test() {
  Cleaner cleaner;
     
  std::shared_ptr<Data> current_data;
  while (true) {
    current_data = createData();

    /* Do something */
      
    // This will reset the current_data ptr, but the actual destructor-call
    // will be done inside the Cleaner thread.
    cleaner.run(current_data);
  }
}
```

I may add the following observations:
Instead of using patterns like this, it's of course preferable to design a proper memory management system, so that there is no need to re-allocate the data on each loop.

Also, if there is another shared_ptr keeping the data alive, the thread will not not destroy any data since the ref count would not reach 0 within the runCleanerLoop function.

Comment: One question per Stackoverflow question, please.

Comment: This post seems to suit code review rather than SO: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The idea is sound, although you have to **drain** `state->queue` entirely since it’s possible that two calls to `run` occur before the next iteration in `runCleanerloop` (or `done` might get set).  (This also means you don’t actually have to worry about **spurious** wakeups: they just elicit 0 work and another `wait`.)

(Separately, it’s not clear why you use a `std::shared_ptr` for `state`: `Cleaner` is merely movable thanks to the `std::thread`, and the `State` outlives the thread even without it.)

Answer (score 2):

Though I think the post belongs to a code review forum (rather than a question usenet group), In this reply I am going to present an alternate approach the problem. If a garbage collection schema is required, I'd just use the deleter version of `std::shared_ptr`:

```
shared_ptr<T> t {
    create_T(),
    [my_gc](T* t){
         post(my_gc,[t]{delete t;});
    }
};
```

Implementing `my_gc` becomes very simple with [**asio**](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context.html):

```
class MY_GC{
      struct impl{
             impl(): busy{ ctx }  
             { worker = std::jthread{[this]{ctx.run();}; };

             boost::asio::io_context ctx;
             std::jthread worker;
             boost::asio::executor_work_guard
                  <boost::asio::io_context::executor_type>
             busy;
      };
public:
      MY_GC():
           ptr{std::make_shared<impl>()}
      {};

      friend void post(MY_GC self, auto what)
      { post(self.impl->ctx, std::move(what)); };
private:
      std::shared_ptr<impl> ptr;
};

MY_GC my_gc;
```

You can wrap the posting of deleter in another class, but I just skip the details.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't reviewed the code thoroughly, just want to comment on the design idea.

### The idea to call `cleaner.run()` explicitly to delete an object, assumes that you know *exactly when* to do so.

Which is hardly compatible with the concept of `shared_ptr`, the whole point of which is to provide automatic lifetime control, when the caller *doesn't know* whether destroying a given instance of `shared_ptr` will delete the object or not.

With shared_ptr it's so easy to forget that you have another copy still alive. Consider this example:

```
Cleaner cleaner;
std::shared_ptr<Data> current_data = createData();
auto                  surprise = current_data;
cleaner.run(current_data); // Will it destroy the Data object? Subject to races...
```

So, if you really *know* when to delete the target object, then use `unique_ptr` and move them around.

### Guarantees provided by the `Cleaner` resembles those of a garbage collector, rather than those of a C++ destructor.

Your basic C++ destructor guarantees that all resources are freed (and all other side effects have occured) before the control is returned to the caller thread. The Cleaner class does not, and it provides no way for the caller to check whether the destruction is performed or not yet.

This might be important in certain cases, for example when dealing with system-global resources, when you must be sure that the resource is freed before attempting to allocate it again:

```
Cleaner cleaner;
std::shared_ptr<Data> current_data = createData();
cleaner.run(current_data);
current_data = createData();  // Will it succeed if the previous instance isn't destroyed yet?
```